# SQL Server 2008 - Log file out of control & cant shrink it

Tags: sql-server-2008, shrink, truncate, transaction-log

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space)

I am having trouble with my database, the log files is currently 250GB in size, I need to shrink this down somehow.

I have tried backing up the transactional log files, performing a full backup, running various shrink scripts but to no avail.

What are the correct steps to make this happen?

Can I somehow just truncate the whole log file then perform a full backup?

Thank You,
Paul

Comment: Not much to work on here. Can you detail the scripts you've run along with the output/observations? Also run [this](https://gist.github.com/raw/1449116/f66960956434049f7af8fb4f9501d3cd3259d711/gistfile1.txt) and add the output to your question.

Comment: Run DBCC OPENTRAN and see if there are any open transactions that are holding onto the log file.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need point it time recovery?  If not then change the database's recovery model to Simple.

Does the database have mirroring or replication configured?  That can also cause the transaction log to blow up quite large.

Comment: You can find the exact reason for the log not reusing space with SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases on 2005 or higher.  This will give you a value you can lookup from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414.aspx for how to resolve the problem.  One note is that REPLICATION could mean Change Data Capture since it uses the Replication Log reader for data collection.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Randal has a good post on this topic: http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Search-Engine-QA-1-Running-out-of-transaction-log-space.aspx